# TfidfVectorizer dtype mismatch

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the TfidfVectorizer on a corpus but every time I end up with this error

```
File "sparsefuncs.pyx", line 117, in sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_csr_row_normalize_l2 (sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs.c:2328)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long long'
```

This is my code

```
corpus = []
testCorpus = []
trainType = []
testType = []

with open("stone_sku.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in cr:
        corpus.append(row['sku'])
        trainType.append(row['sku'])

with open("stone_sku.csv") as f:
    crTest = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in crTest:
        testCorpus.append(row['sku'])
        testType.append(row['sku'])

cv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2,3))

trainCounts = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
```

It works fine with CountVectorizer and the same error occurs if I try to transform the data using TfidfTransformer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running 64 bit Windows? This might be caused by a known issue that has been recently fixed in the master branch.

Comment: Yes I am, so I gather there's something in 3.3 that's causing this? I just tried it in 3.2 and it works, thanks.

Comment: Have you built scikit-learn from source? Or do you use the binary of the last released version?