# kmeans scikit-learn tutorial

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying out Python instead of R for data analysis and am having a bit of trouble. So I've been reading scikit-learn's documentation and tried running their kmeans example on my own but get this error message:

> Extracting features from the training dataset using a sparse vectorizer
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "kmeans.py", line 104, in 
>       X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset.data)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1238, in fit_transform
>       return self._tfidf.transform(X, copy=False)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1010, in transform
>       X = normalize(X, norm=self.norm, copy=False)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 542, in normalize
>       inplace_csr_row_normalize_l2(X)
>
> File "sparsefuncs.pyx", line 146, in sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs.inplace_csr_row_normalize_l2 (sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.c:2714)
>
> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'

For reference, the code is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_clustering.html

It took me a bit of fiddling to get the whole scipy stack but I'm sure I have it now, just wondering why copy-pasting their code and then running it would give an error (I'm sure they wouldn't put code with a bug on their site). Any idea on what the fix is/ what's happening?

Comment: Are you running Windows 64-bit? Your issue maybe related to this which is a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775997/tfidfvectorizer-dtype-mismatch

Comment: No this is on a 64-bit Mac and Python 2.7.2

Comment: You are looking at the documentation for 0.14. Try with the dev version: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/document_clustering.html. The code is actually different.

Comment: That's true but running this other code still produces the same error from the replicated line. Has the code worked for you @DanielVelkov?

Comment: I'm running 0.14 and have no problems with the code.

Comment: @wannaC Yes by downloading Anaconda. I later wiped my hard drive and re-downloaded all the dependencies (without Anaconda), and it ended up working also. So it all had to do with mismatched dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the scipy stack? I strongly suggest that you don't try to assemble a stack yourself, as it is quite challenging to do. I would rather push you to use anaconda https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/.

Disclaimer: 1) I don't work these guys. 2) anaconda has a free version. It's good.

Answer (score 0):

One helpful approach is to install Anaconda and the PyCharm or Eclipse IDE. Point your intepreter from the IDE to the Anaconda lib. Refer to this link for more guide: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration.html. Plus it is supereasy to update pkgs including scikit with "conda update" and "anaconda update" from the shell.